# python site-packages (2.7 to 3.7) macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a new macOS user and installed python 3.7 (the default was 2.7).
I recently cloned a repository from github with its own `setup.py` script.
Running this script `python setup.py` I get:

```
    /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist. Please create it and try again, or choose a different installation directory
```

I am satisfied that this is true. If I go into `/Library/Python/` I can see there is no `3.7` directory; however, I do have the `2.7/site-packages` (default) directory. This has confused me.

If I use `python --version` I get `Python 3.7.3`.

If I use `python -m site` I am given:

```
USER_BASE: '/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.7' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
```

I have noted that the following `2.7` directories exist:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7
/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

Here, the contents of the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and `/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` differ considerably.

What is going on? And should I have a `/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/` dictionary to (properly) install my program?

Essentially, where is my `/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/` dictionary and why does the installation differ from `2.7`?

I think I am looking for the `Extras.pth, README, easy-install.pth, nose-1.3.7-py3.7.egg` version of files for `python 3.7`.